# Android ArrayList<Keyframe> to Keyframe

Tags: android, arraylist, variadic-functions

My question is how to adapt `ArrayList`<`Keyframe`> object, that it fits in the function `PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe`(`String` propertyName, `Keyframe`... values) as a `Keyframe...` parameter?
I assume that ofKeyframe() is a varargs function, so looked for an answer with that in mind, tried to use toArray() function on ArrayList object, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe(String propertyName, yourList.toArray())
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])

Comment: I tried both .toArray() and .toArray(Keyframe[]) (i assume T stands for the Class-type). All i get is an error, that i`m trying to insert Object[] instead of "Keyframes..."

Comment: Did you tried this?
PropertyValuesHolder.ofKeyframe(property, list.toArray(new Keyframe[0]));

Comment: Thanks, that removed the error, tho the app still doesnt work as i expected, but that is outside this topic question range. P.s. What exactly the "0" in square brackets mean - the size of the created array or it points to the first element of newly created array?

Comment: According method description, we should pass array for storing list elements, but if passed array too small for all elements, method will not use our array, create new array with required size and return it as result. So, it simply to pass 0-sized array and get needed array as result.

Comment: I see. In my case i can avoid "array-size-too-small" case, because i have a definite amount of Keyframes, so i`ll just use that value instead of putting 0 (if understand correctly, that way the function for returning new array will execute less commands.)